# mathematics for drawing little lines around circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have to draw lines around a circle (like in clock). How can i achieve this using a for loop?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do the actual drawing of a line in Java but to calculate co-ordinates from a central point `(cx,cy)` use

```
px = cx+sin(a)*r
py = cy+cos(a)*r
```

Where `a` is the angle (in radians - I think ie 180 degress=π radians) and `r` is the radius.

To draw the little lines around the outside you would need to use this formula with say a radius of 100 and the also with a radius of 105 and draw between the two sets of co-ordinates.

eg

```
for (var a=0,aMax=(2*Math.PI),aStep=(Math.PI/30); a<aMax; a+=aStep){
    px1 = cx+Math.sin(a)*r;
    py1 = cy+Math.cos(a)*r;
    px2 = cx+Math.sin(a)*(r+5);
    py2 = cy+Math.cos(a)*(r+5);

    //draw line between (px1,py1) and (px2,py2)
};
```

Comment: he was asking about javascript, `java.lang.Math` is a java class, and isn't available in javascript

Comment: It's just `Math` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the source code of [CoolClock](http://randomibis.com/coolclock/).

Comment: I don't think browsing through a complex code (it supports skins - wtf) is worth it when all OP is looking for is a simple calculation..

Comment: The skins should contain the code to draw the lines. This code should be pretty simple. Moreover, looking at code from other people is always a good learning experience.

Comment: @poke Agreeed, the OP wants to "draw lines around a circle" - not implement a fullblown clock. The goal may be totally un-clock related but just clock *like*

Comment: But if you have no idea how those lines are drawn you will have a very hard time understanding the code and finding the actual bit you are interested in..

Answer (score 1):

you should read up on basic trigonometry and focus on [Quadrants](http://www.mathwizz.com/algebra/help/help29.htm) to achieve that.