# Creating dashes in a pattern of a circle using Javascript Math

Tags: javascript, loops, math, canvas, trigonometry

I don't understand a lot about the code below and I would like someone to break it down piece by piece.

```js
$(function() {
  var centerX = 200,
    centerY = 200,
    radius = 100,
    width = 15,
    angles = []

  function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var angle;
    //why 180 
    for (var i = 0; i < 180; i += 10) {
      //is the "angle" increasing on every iteration? can you demostrate this please
      angle = 2.1 + (i * Math.PI / 90);
      angles.push(angle)
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(
        centerX + Math.sin(angle) * radius,
        centerY + Math.cos(angle) * radius
      );
      ctx.lineTo(
        centerX + Math.sin(angle) * (radius + width),
        centerY + Math.cos(angle) * (radius + width)
      );
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
  draw()
  console.log(angles)
  var str = "";
  angles.forEach(function(e, i) {
    str += " " + i + " : " + e + "|| Math.sin = " + Math.sin(e) + "|| Math.sin * radius = " + Math.sin(e) * radius
    $(".display").html(str)
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<div class="display"></div>
```

like for this part `angle = 2.1 + (i * Math.PI / 90);` I see `i` is incrementing by 10 and  the author is multiplying it by `Math.PI / 90` which is equal to 0.0348888888888889. I know Math.PI is 180 degrees, but were not doing 180/90. We're increasing the number 2.1 by small amount. I can't put all the pieces together.

and in `for(var i = 0; i < 180; i += 10){` why did the author choose 180. I know 180 degrees is a half a circle is that why they chose it?

And I always see in other code people use `cos` for the x coord and `sin` for the y coord. It doesn't look like the author uses it like the way i just described. could you elaborate.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I'm also wondering when we use `for(var i = 0; i < 180; i += 10){` we get the dashes in a full circle and when i do `i < 90` we get a half a circle but the half circle is not straight like against an x or y axis its on an angle. why is it not on the axis? why is it on an angle?

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont understand problem statement fully. Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rajesh the problem is I don't understand how the code produces the output. and I would like someone to explain it to me in detail.

Comment: Just saying that I got the code from this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810768/mathematics-for-drawing-little-lines-around-circle

Comment: Have updated a code bit but now it prints perfect semi-circle. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/fj32o631/). I dont know the significance of `2.1` , so have omitted it. Hope it helps

Comment: @Rajesh. The `2.1` roughly adjusts the starting angle of the circle to start at the 12 o'clock position rather than the 3 o'clock position. It's not really needed here since the code navigates the entire circle ;-)

Comment: @markE in following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/fj32o631/), if you change condition to `<90`, then you will notice semi-circle will form till 1 o'clock. Per my understanding, its starting from 6 o'clock.

Comment: @Rajesh. Oops! I did the math in my head incorrectly. But the purpose of `2.1` is to adjust the angle by a fixed amount before adjusting it further with `i`. Thanks for double checking my math! :-)

Comment: @Rajesh   `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i += 10){` is one iteration  and that shows  that it starts at around 3 oclock right? because `centerY + Math.cos(angle) * radius` == `200 + Math.cos(2.1) * 100` == `149.51538954001424` .. this is the y coord of the first iteration which is araond 3 oclock not 6 o'clock or 12 o'clock.. right?.. now I'm confused on how the author is using using cos to get y cords. This applies to the original code in the question

Comment: @markE and user2537537, apologies! I had removed 2.1 and hence I was getting it from 6 o'clock. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/fj32o631/1/) depicting that. Also I don't think I have enough Maths knowledge to challenge/comment about it, but  I guess (not sure), we can get desired result without `2.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with **SOH CAH TOA** ([link](http://www.mathwords.com/s/sohcahtoa.htm)).

Given Right angled triangle (one side is 90 deg)..

- Triangle has an angle.
- Triangle has a side that's Opposite (**O**) to the angle.
- Triangle has side that touches both, the angle and the right angle, called (**A**) Adjacent Side.
- Triangle has a side that is called Hypotenuse (**H**). This is the side that also touches the Angle but doesn't make a right angle with Opposite side.

[image]

Now to find any side you need to know at minimum the angle and 1 another side.

**Ex:** You know angle, Q, is 40deg and Hypotenuse is 10. So what is Adjacent;

Looking at **SOH CAH TOA**. I See that I know H, and need to know A. CAH has both. So I choose CAH.

```
Cos Q = Adj/Hyp
```

Now if you put this Triangle inside circle. Then `Hyp` will become the **radius**, like so:

[image]

```
Cos Q = Adj/radius
```

Now to draw line going outward from a circle i need to know a starting point and the ending point of a line AND i need to make those points align with circle angles.

To get starting point i can just use circle's boundary.

So to get x,y for a point on circle boundary i solve this equation further..

```
Cos Q * radius = Adj

Cos Q * radius = x //adj is x
```

& for y...

```
SOH
Sin Q = Opp/Hyp
Sin Q = Opp/radius
Sin Q * radius = Opp
Sin Q * radius = y
```

So

```
x = Cos Q * radius
y = Sin Q * radius

or in js..

var x = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
var y = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
```

Now we have points that follow a circle's boundary. But for there to be line like we want, we need two points.

This code simply puts in a bigger radius, which gives bigger circle, which gives 2nd points what we needed.

```
 ctx.lineTo(
        centerX + Math.sin(angle) * (radius + width),
        centerY + Math.cos(angle) * (radius + width));
```

Code Formatted to be clear:

```
var centerX = 200,
    centerY = 200,
    radius = 100,
    width = 15,
    angles = [],
    ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

function draw() {
    var angle;

    for (var i = 0; i < 180; i += 10) {

        angle = 2.1 + (i * Math.PI / 90);

        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.moveTo(
        centerX + Math.sin(angle) * radius,
        centerY + Math.cos(angle) * radius);

        ctx.lineTo(
        centerX + Math.sin(angle) * (radius + width),
        centerY + Math.cos(angle) * (radius + width));

        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}

draw();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was really helpful. I still have questions.You wrote `Cos Q * radius = x //adj is x` this finds the length of the adjacent  side of the triangle? not the length of the radius. so we take the length which is from the origin to what ever `Cos Q * radius = x //adj is x` is and we go up to whatever `Sin Q * radius = y` and this gives us the point on the circle? correct? I have more questions about updating the angle. just one at a time. TIA.

Comment: Correct, that's the starting point, then we repeat the same process but with bigger circle that gives us 2nd point, now we can make a whole line

Answer (score 1):

The code you cite is a bit awkward.

To navigate around a circle, it would be more clear to increment `i` from 0 to 360 (as in 360 degrees).

```
for(var i=0; i<360; i++){
```

Instead, the coder increments from 0 to 180, but then they compensate for halving the 360 degrees by doubling the formula that converts degrees to radians.

```
// this is the usual conversion of degrees to radians
var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;

// This "compensating" conversion is used by the coder
// This doubling of the conversion compensates for halving "i" to 180
var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 90;
```

A clearer factoring of the iteration would look like this:

```
// the conversion factor to turn degrees into radians
var degreesToRadians = Math.PI / 180;

// navigate 360 degrees around a circle
for(var i=0; i<360; i++){

    // use the standard degrees-to-radians conversion factor
    var angle = i * degreesToRadians;

    // This roughly rotates the angle so that it starts
    // at the 12 o'clock position on the circle
    // This is unnecessary if you're navigating completely
    // around the circle anyway (then it doesn't matter where you start)
    angle += 2.1;

    ....

}
```

And...

The code is intentionally drawing lines that radiate away from the circles circumference. The coder is not attempting to follow the circumference at all.

Comment: Thank you for your response it helped me understand some things. I'm confused about what you said about the angle 2.1 making the rotation around the circle start at 12 o'clock. I see the first iteration starts at around 3 'o'clock. and goes counterclockwise for the moveTo x,y cords.

Comment: You're welcome! About `2.1`: This is an angle expressed in radians. So if you convert it to degrees you get: `2.1 radians * 180 / PI == approx. 120 degrees`. Zero degrees is at 3 o'clock so 120 degrees would be 7 o'clock. But since we're navigating a complete circle it doesn't really matter if we start a 3 or 7 o'clock. ;-)